# Database (OLTP) and Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I am working on a trading platform that has reporting as a big portion of its business.

**The set up is the following:**
SQL OLTP database (about 200 tables) – rather small in number of records. (20,000 records the biggest table – but keeps growing every week)
For reporting services, SQL views are being used to query the Live Transaction Database. Imagine the result set of the views a de-normalized one, in the spirit of a data warehouse approach. Then these data sets are passed to a third party Reporting platform (like Tableau, Power Bi or SiSense), which take these data sets and throws them into Cubes (probably some columnar structure, like mono db, hadoop, etc). From there the Reports are getting generated.

**Current challenges.**
The SQL views (about 8). Are huge and very hard to maintain. To give you an example, one of the views outputs 100 fields. But each of these fields are calculated fields with complicated CASE statements, nested IF statements, inline Functions, and what not, which makes this view as big as 700 lines of sql code. I inherited these from anther employee and now, **sadly**, I have to maintain them.
Because the data grows weekly by several hundreds records (through migration and transactions) and the number of fields in the views also grow (a few every week), the cube building takes longer and longer. To give you an example, few months ago we set up the cube re-built ever 10 minutes to refresh the data (which was taking 5 minutes). Currently takes 12-15 minutes to build, so we set it up every 30 minutes. As you can imagine, this will get worse as data and the number of fields keep growing; and we kind of need the data as current as possible.

The only good thing is that once the cube is built, the reports load fast because they are being pulled form the 3rd party platform, so no concerns here.

**What I have in mind**
I would like to get rid of the views so I could ease the process of maintenanace and also keep at minimum the duration of the cube re-built.

**Options:**

1. to build a data warehouse. And then build SSIS packages to populate this structure with the live transactional data. The de-normalized structure would probably look very similar the views mentioned above. The draw back here is that I don’t really feel like I simplify much, actualy adding one more layer, which is the data migration from the OLTP to the OLAP (datawarehouse). And I would still have to re-build the cube.
2. To turn the current views into SQL Indexed Views (materialized views), but in their current state, I simply cannot do it because of the agregate and inline functions used a lot across the entire view.
3. Another option I red about is to built a ODS (Operational Data Store – which would be a databse that would contain the necessary tables similar to the sql views I have now – and refresh it constantly) Maybe using triggers, or, Transaction logs? But I am not sure what involves to built such thing and how hard is to maintain.

**Question:** 
What approach should I take? 
Do any of the 3 above make any sense? 
**Of course, I am interested in other ideas or suggestions, as well.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

from my experience your best approach will be 1. It is costly, but will give you better benefits . Create a ROLAP DWH(i recommend Kimball's "The data warehouse toolkit" for best practices and design patterns), if you have the oportunity use a columnar data store(like amazon redshift, or sap  sybase iq) and all the case statements ,nested ifs and all operations that you mentioned, would be applied on ETL time, so in the ROLAP everything is precalculated and optimized to consumption. And dont forget about aplying indexes(depending on the relying technology you use) . Some database vendors already published "indexing best practices" for ROLAP so they will tell you which type of index aply depending of the type of table(dimension) and data type for example.

Comment: Hi Luis Leal. Thank you for your reply.

Yes, the number 1 was my first option, but currently data is refreshed every 30 minutes through the cube in SiSense, and we want to keep it the same, not much longer than 30 min. So by building the data warehouse, means I will add complexity to the process through anther layer - which is the ETL, which would prolong the time of having data refreshed.

Comment: So instead of one process right now, through the SQL Views, which pulls straight from Live, would be the packages, with the necessary logic (all those case statements), that would pull the data form live into DW. Then the SiSense cube still needs to pull it from these data warehouse tables. Also, they keep changing the logic of how to pull those fields through the case statements, and I am wondering if maintenance wouldn't worse, doing it inside SSIS, instead SQL views. So, I am still confused what is the best approach. :)